# Extra button keeps appearing

Tags: java, swing

I'm kind of new to java and I experienced this little problem on every computer I run my program.
My code is

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FrameTest2 {


    public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "Catch Torchic";

    MainMenu m = new MainMenu(s);
    }
}

class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    JButton autoa, manualb, createc, exitd;

    public MainMenu(String s){
        super(s);
        setBackground(new Color(247,247,111));
        setSize(640,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();
        panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        panel.setBackground(new Color(247,247,111));
        contentPane.add(panel);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(btnPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        btnPanel.setBackground(new Color(247,247,111));
        autoa = new JButton("AutoPlay");
        autoa.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(autoa);

        manualb = new JButton("Manual Play");
        manualb.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(manualb);

        createc = new JButton("Create Maze");
        createc.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(createc);

        exitd = new JButton("Exit");
        exitd.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(exitd);

        btnPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.add(btnPanel);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler(this);
        autoa.addActionListener(handler);
        manualb.addActionListener(handler);
        createc.addActionListener(handler);
        exitd.addActionListener(handler);
}

}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    MainMenu mm;

    public ButtonHandler(MainMenu mm){
        this.mm = mm;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == mm.autoa)
        System.out.println("Clicked on Auto");
        else if(e.getSource() == mm.manualb)
        System.out.println("Clicked on Manual");
        else if(e.getSource() == mm.createc)
        System.out.println("Clicked on Create");
        else 
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent (Graphics painter){

    Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("logo.png");
    if(pic != null) painter.drawImage(pic, 105, 30, this); 

    }
}
```

This code results into this: http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/318155_424290814251286_100000111130260_1871937_131988334_n.jpg

where there is always the extra button on the upper left corner, My question is, how do I remove this? the button appears at random intervals, sometimes it does not.

Comment: 1) *"This code results into.."*  Compilation errors.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: I tried your code with no change and it's work verry well, like you can see in this pic : http://hpics.li/acc7d7d.

Comment: I edited the code and placed all the classes.
I did not use Eclipse, netbeans or the like. I just used Notepad++.

Comment: BTW - if you start a comment with @PersonName they will be notified of the comment.  Please do that in future, I only realized that the problem now had code, because I revisited to check it.  I expect Eric & others still do not know.

Comment: +1 for posting code.  Note re. my 2nd point, I can't read code until that (logical indent) is done.  My example uses what I feel is  a logical system.  Have a look over the two sources and see in which it is easier to tell when code blocks begin & end. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant.  Many comments, the most important in SHOUTING.  Note that by the time I had got it to being working code (or rather, code that worked here for loading the image), I never once saw the problem you describe.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class FrameTest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String s = "Catch Torchic";
        URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/stromlo2.jpg");
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(url);

        //Create the frame on the event dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu(s, image);
            }

        });
    }
}

class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    JButton autoa, manualb, createc, exitd;

    public MainMenu(String s, Image image) {
        super(s);
        // do this after pack (if at all)
        //setSize(640,600);
        // do this after pack/setSize
        //setVisible(true);
        // don't do this in broken code
        //setResizable(false);
        // If you're going to spend space on GUI position..
        // setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // ..do it like this.
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel(image);
        panel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        //panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        //panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600,365));
        contentPane.add(panel);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,100,5));
        btnPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(btnPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        // not needed for an SSCCE
        //btnPanel.setBackground(new Color(247,247,111));
        autoa = new JButton("AutoPlay");
        autoa.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(autoa);

        manualb = new JButton("Manual Play");
        manualb.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(manualb);

        createc = new JButton("Create Maze");
        createc.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(createc);

        exitd = new JButton("Exit");
        exitd.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        btnPanel.add(exitd);

        // you already said that
        //btnPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        contentPane.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler(this);
        autoa.addActionListener(handler);
        manualb.addActionListener(handler);
        createc.addActionListener(handler);
        exitd.addActionListener(handler);

        // CAUSE THE COMPONENTS TO BE PROPERLY LAID OUT.
        pack();
        setSize(640,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}

class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    MainMenu mm;

    public ButtonHandler(MainMenu mm){
        this.mm = mm;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        // for clarity, even single line statements 
        // in these should be enclosed in {}
        if(e.getSource() == mm.autoa)
            System.out.println("Clicked on Auto");
        else if(e.getSource() == mm.manualb)
            System.out.println("Clicked on Manual");
        else if(e.getSource() == mm.createc)
            System.out.println("Clicked on Create");
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }

}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel{

    Image pic;

    CustomPanel(Image pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics painter){
        // DO NOT TRY TO READ IMAGES IN PAINT!
        //Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("logo.png");
        if(pic != null) painter.drawImage(pic, 105, 30, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("logo.png");` will most likely fail at time of deployment, since the code is trying to access (what will presumably be) an 'embedded' app. resource as though it were a `File`.  These must be accessed by `URL`.

Comment: thank you very much sir!
Questions:
why get the image from a URL? Can't I have it together with the class?
pack() gets the components to be laid out properly?

Comment: 1) An `URL` can point to an entry in a Jar file - in fact, it is the only way to access a resource in a Jar (using Java).  Any `File` path on your local file system can also be turned into an URL, using `File.toURI().toURL()`.  In short, URLs are much more versatile. 2) It should also work that way.  Use  `Class.getResource(String)` to get the URL. 3) Yes.  I think that was perhaps causing the layout problem, but reading an image in the paint method is ***never*** a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the missing `contentPane.`:

```
    //setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));//
```

Also there is a superfluous setting of the content pane.

```
    //setContentPane(contentPane);
```

---

***After "nope:"***

*Difficult.*
Move `setVisible(true)` to the end, to invoke only one layouting.
Try it without two panels (only one) inside the content pane:

```
    Container contentPane0 = getContentPane();
    Container contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane0.add(contentPane);
```